Windows Server 2022 Permission denied when submitting a certificate request
We are using Windows to host our internal CA server for all internal web server, and other TLS secured services, certificates. Before the upgrade to server 2022, from 2016 if I remember correctly, I was able to submit a certificate request to the CA, via the desktop as IIS isn't set up, and get a certificate issued. As many of these certificates are for Linux services and the request is created via OpenSSL or Java I use a batch file with the following command to start the process: certreq -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer".
After the upgrade I have been getting the following error when attempting to get a certificate issued. Certificate not issued (Denied) Denied by Policy Module The permissions on the certificate template do not allow the current user to enroll for this type of certificate. 0x80094012 (-2146877422 CERTSRV_E_TEMPLATE_DENIED)
I did find this 4sysops.com page and from what I understand of it I need to add the computer that is making the request to the Security page for the template with Read and Enroll rights. The computers in question are Linux boxes and many of them are not in AD, including the one I am attempting to get a certificate for, so I cannot add that system to the security settings. I did try adding the CA server, and the Domain Computers group, to the template security settings with no change. I also verified that the Domain Admins group, of which my account is a member, had the Read and *Enroll rights assigned.
And now, the questions. How can I get around this issue? Am I required to add the system to AD? Can I change a setting somewhere to avoid that? If that's not possible would I need to setup a sub-CA on a Linux box just for these non-AD systems?
Edit: Added my accounts permission info for the template.

How are the permissions for the user account conferred? Are they a member of a group?

@GregAskew I've updated the question with my user account permissions. Basically the account falls under the domain admins group which has read and enroll permissions set.

Have you tested this locally or from a Windows host with certreq and using a CSR file?

I do not have a Windows host with IIS available to test with. Testing with a Linux host that is in AD has the same issue. Both before and after I added that host and the CA host to the Certificate Template security settings.

Certreq.exe tool uses currently logged-in account to authenticate requester on CA. This means that your currently logged-in account must have Read and Enroll permissions on template.
If you are using Domain Admins group for permissions, be aware that your CMD/PowerShell console (where you run certreq.exe) must be executed in elevated mode, because UAC typically strip sensitive groups from your token.
